# Why is the atom loss rate enhanced at the Feshbach resonance?

Tags: atomic-physics, bose-einstein-condensate, cold-atoms

At the Feshbach resonance, the scattering length is enhanced. But why is the atom loss also enhanced?

Comment: Maybe you could expand your question a bit more and give some context, then it might be easier to give a good answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scattering length is basically a crude measure of how much interaction there is, so if you have a cold atomic gas in a trap, and it starts to interact more, then naturally atoms get kicked out of the trap by these interactions. This is then detected by enhanced loss rates.

Depending on the setup you can get very weakly bound states (for example Efimov states, if the scattering length is much larger than natural length scale of your problem, in most cases this is the van der Waals length) which do not respond to the trap and/or the detection mechanism anymore and are therefore also lost.